# Remember checkboxes in Smarty engine

Tags: php, html, checkbox, smarty

How can I remember checkboxes in Smarty when I create them dynamically?
If a user fills in a webform and he submits the page and there are errors they are always gone. (The ones that are checked)

I should have a way to store them.

Currently I set them the following way (in a {foreach}:

```
{html_checkboxes values=$event@key output=$event@key selected=$event id=$event@value name=$event checked="1"}
```

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

That question isn't Smarty-specific in my eyes. It can be done in more than one way. Two examples to demonstrate how to cope with this:

1. Use a JScript libraries form validator to validate the data before submitting. An example if you're using JQuery can be found here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ (there are many more out there for nearly every JScript library, I just chose JQuery as an example because its current widely acceptance).
2. Don't transfer the form data to your server using the form submit, use some AJAX to submit them and wait for a response from your server. If the response is "oops, error", show the user the field which contains the error.

Again, there's more than those ways of doing it, but - depending on what the form does - those two are usually the fastest and easiest to implement.